# How do I refactor JavaScript code to TypeScript when it uses Object.create to define its public interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring

I'm working on some legacy code I didn't write, trying to refactor it to typescript. Some of the patterns confuse TS type inference and usually TS shrugs and says, "Your guess is as good as mine, buddy. Let's say `any`." This is one such pattern:

```js
var X = (() => {
  // ^? var X: any
  const foo = "foo string";

  function xBar() {
    console.log("xBar log");
    return 5;
  }

  return Object.preventExtensions(Object.create(null, {
    foo: {
      value: foo
    },
    bar: {
      value: xBar
    },
  }));
})();
```

[I've done some research and found `Object.create` to be the culprit.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3865) It's hard coded to return `any`. I'm not sure why that issue was closed without a stated reason. Regardless...

That `any` isn't very helpful. This is my desired type:

```
var X: {
  foo: string /* or "foo string" */;
  bar: () => number;
};
```

I can get that by writing the type definition by hand like so:

```
  declare var X: {
    foo: string /* or "foo string" */;
    bar: () => number;
  };

  X = (() => {
  const foo = 'foo string';

  function xBar() {
    console.log('xBar log');
    return 5;
  }

  return Object.preventExtensions(
    Object.create(null, {
      foo: {
        value: foo,
      },
      bar: {
        value: xBar,
      },
    })
  );
})();
```

But this is quite painstaking, especially when the `Object.create` values (e.g., `foo`, `xBar`, etc.) are complex and `any` types, too.

Is there a refactoring* I could do to get that desired type without having to write it by hand?

UPDATE: [I found an open issue for a narrower `Object.create` return type.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39882)

UPDATE2: [Maybe the advice in this github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37141#issuecomment-593114253) provides a solution to my `Object.create` issue?

---

* By refactoring, I mean changing the code's structure without changing its behavior. This code has no automated tests (yet), so the less changes I have to make, the better.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255370/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-kaplan-how-do-i-refactor-javascript-code-to-typ); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.